Landau theory fourth power
As I understand Landau theory, we assume we can express the Landau Free Energy as a polynomial in the order parameter, and then argue that since the order parameter is small in the region of interest, we can ignore terms higher than the fourth order.
We then argue that the coefficient of the fourth order term must be positive, to ensure that there is a bounded minimum.
This seems rather arbitrary. If we had claimed that we could ignore terms greater than second order, we would argue that the coefficient of the second order term must be positive. And if we'd claimed we need terms up to 6th order, we would have nothing to say about the fourth order coefficient.
Is there any justification (beyond "it works in practice") for choosing to run the expansion up to fourth order specifically?

This is justified by the Renormalization Group and the fact that most terms in the Landau Expansion are "irrelevant". The 4th order term is "relevant" in 3D. I let you google "relevant operator renormalization group" (the renormalization group wiki page also has a section about that) to know a bit more

It is phenomenological, if it works it works

The Landau model is only meant to be a simple qualitative model for phase transitions, and a symmetric quartic polynomial (with positive leading coefficient) has a simple formula for the minimum/minima.  At the time, data for second order phase transitions was relatively messy, and the relevance of fluctuations wasn't entirely understood, and so it was reasonable to posit an explanation for second order phase transitions that could be formulated in simple algebra.  The main insight is the that critical exponents and divergent susceptibilities are a defining feature of second order phase transitions, and it paved the way for the theory of scaling relations between critical exponents, statistical field theory, the renormalization group, and universality.
It is perfectly acceptable to consider more complex Landau theories with sixth degree polynomials (or even appropriately shaped odd-degree polynomials, as approximate theories describing a neighborhood of the equilibrium configuration.)  Typically, however, as you vary an experimental parameter (i.e. a "generic" smooth curve in the parameter space of the theory) you will tend to see plain-old first order transitions as the relevant local minima shift, and as you vary pairs of experimental parameters (i.e. "generic" surfaces in the parameter space of the theory) you will find a landscape of segments describing first order transitions terminated by second order critical points.  Generically, you need three or more experimentally tunable parameters to observe higher order transitions; hence, while these transitions may exist, and can be interesting in appropriate dimensions (where fluctuations may or may not modify the critical exponents from their Landau-theory values), they are very challenging to produce experimentally.
